# Is it possible to have a 1/2 compression ratio with arithmetic coding and how

Tags: compression

Need light on arithmetic compression.
Currently I work on data compression more particular that arithmetic one. I would like to compress an integer vector between 1 and 255.
My vector is of size 256 or 512 .... My problem is that after applying the arithmetic coding I find myself with a compression ratio almost zero.
So my question is the following is it possible to have a 1/2 compression ratio with arithmetic coding and how.
Thank you in advance and forgive my bad english. This is not my native language.

Comment: Show us your code. I wish I didn't guess the wrong code.

Comment: Sure. If there is enough redundancy in the data. What is your data?

Comment: I agree with you dear Mark Adler. Then I will detake my problem a little clearer as Mr. SteveFest will see what is wrong.
Here I would like to compress a matrix of integer elements. The elements are between 1 and 256. The size of my matrix can vary from 510 to 65534 elements.

  Mark Adler you're right the compression rate depends on the number of redundancy but me I more than what i have right now. I get to compress but at best I nai that 15% as compression ratio.
I put my compression algorithm. Maybe you will find an average to improve it or offer me another algorithm if possible.

Comment: **Edit the Question** with the information . Not the comments